# Update label option of attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, script, installer

I try to update labels options on my size label in an installer.
I use the following code :

```
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'size_label');
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);

$attribute->setData('option', array(
    'value'=> array($optionId => array (
        0 => 'default label',
        1 => 'FR label',
        2 => 'DE label',
        3 => 'ES label',
        [...]
        )),
    'order' => array($optionId => $orderId)
    )
);

$attribute->save();
```

This code work when I use it like a script, but if I use it in my installer, there is an issue on this line :

```
$attribute->save();
```

In both case, `$attribute->getData()` return the same array..

When I launch the installer, that remove all my label (even the default one "default label"), but I still have the line on my BO with the position.

Someone now what could be the difference between the script and the installer ? Why that work in the first one and not in the second one ? Any idea ?

Comment: What is $orderId and $optionId here?

Comment: Just simple numbers (examples : "520" or "286").

Comment: So basically you want to add options for your size attribute through installer. Right?

Comment: I want update label option for my size attribute (for each store). Sorry if it's not clear :S

Comment: Understand. So your code is showing only for one option to update. Right?

Comment: Yes, only 1 option, but several labels (one for each store)

Comment: Ok I ll check and update you.

Comment: Did you find any explanation ? Or another way to do it ?